# how to connect with mysql from any mobile

Tags: mysql, kivy

I have a problem, I'm making an app that connects to a database, I've been using free hostings and I've never had problems connecting to the database, a few days ago I made a Google Cloud account and made one database and it turns out that now it only connects when I am connected to my wifi.
I guess it has something to do with my ip but I'm kind of lost, I'm kind of new to this
I get the following error when I try to log in:

```
04-01 13:04:20.634  5095  5123 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-01 13:04:20.635  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/network.py", line 600, in open_connection
04-01 13:04:20.636  5095  5123 I python  :  TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
04-01 13:04:20.636  5095  5123 I python  :
04-01 13:04:20.637  5095  5123 I python  :  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
04-01 13:04:20.637  5095  5123 I python  :
04-01 13:04:20.637  5095  5123 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-01 13:04:20.637  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1663, in <module>
04-01 13:04:20.638  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
04-01 13:04:20.639  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
04-01 13:04:20.639  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1659, in build
04-01 13:04:20.640  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 305, in load_file
04-01 13:04:20.640  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 407, in load_string
04-01 13:04:20.641  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 660, in _apply_rule
04-01 13:04:20.641  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
04-01 13:04:20.642  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 540, in apply
04-01 13:04:20.642  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
04-01 13:04:20.643  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
04-01 13:04:20.643  5095  5123 I python  :    [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
04-01 13:04:20.643  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 658, in _apply_rule
04-01 13:04:20.644  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 939, in __init__
04-01 13:04:20.644  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/app/base_datos.py", line 118, in leer_tabla_pedido
04-01 13:04:20.645  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 294, in connect
04-01 13:04:20.645  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 167, in __init__
04-01 13:04:20.646  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1178, in connect
04-01 13:04:20.646  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 571, in _open_connection
04-01 13:04:20.647  5095  5123 I python  :    File "/mnt/c/pakagin_1.0/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/pkgapp/arm64-v8a/mysql/connector/network.py", line 602, in open_connection
04-01 13:04:20.647  5095  5123 I python  :  mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.202.36.237:3306' (110 Connection timed out)
04-01 13:04:20.647  5095  5123 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I am using mysql workbench 8.0.32

Comment: You almost never want to have a mobile app connect directly to SQL, unless it's for *administrators* of that SQL database. You'd generally build an API that *accesses* MySQL on the server side.

Comment: I was seeing that they recommended doing that, I have to start reading, from what I saw I have to read about web services, meanwhile I would like to solve my problem, a couple of people are going to use the app